# scss-lint.yml is not working

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I got small problem with scss-lint, I am trying to run in a simple file and after changes in the scss-lint.yml , still not loading my config.

scss file: _headlines.scss

```
// Headlines

%headline-primary {
  @include rem-size(60px);
  color: palette(grey, light); 
  font-weight: $font-weight--book;
  line-height: $line-height-base;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

scss-lint.yml

```
# Default application configuration that all configurations inherit from.

scss_files: "scss/**/*.scss"
plugin_directories: ['.scss-linters']

# List of gem names to load custom linters from (make sure they are already
# installed)
plugin_gems: []

# Default severity of all linters.
severity: warning

linters:
  ColorKeyword:
    enabled: false

  ColorVariable:
    enabled: false
```

command line used:

```
 scss-lint scss/_headlines.scss
```

file sctrucute:

[image]

```
scss/_headlines.scss:5:1 [W] TrailingWhitespace: Line contains trailing whitespace
scss/_headlines.scss:5:18 [W] ColorKeyword: Color `grey` should be written in hexadecimal form as `#808080`
scss/_headlines.scss:5:18 [W] ColorVariable: Color literals like `grey` should only be used in variable declarations; they should be referred to via variable everywhere else.
scss/_headlines.scss:9:1 [W] FinalNewline: Files should end with a trailing newline
```

ColorKeyword is defined as false in my scss-lint.yml but still runing someone know what is happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [scss-lint documentation](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#configuration), the following is specified:

> **Configuration**
>
> scss-lint loads configuration in the following order of precedence:
>
> 1. Configuration file specified via the --config flag
> 2. Configuration from .scss-lint.yml in the current working directory, if it exists
> 3. Configuration from .scss-lint.yml in the user's home directory, if it exists
>
> All configurations extend the default configuration.

There is no `.scss-lint.yml` in your current working directory, `scss-lint-test`. Therefore, it will be using the default configuration.

To solve this, either move your YML file into `scss-lint-test`, or run `scss-lint` from the `scss` folder.